# How to use CreateCompatibleDC(), SetPixel(), and BitBlt() to display an image?

Tags: c++, gdi, visual-studio-2022

I'm trying to draw and display an image(s) on a device context (variable: dc) by using CreateCompatibleDC(), SetPixel(), and BitBlt() as seen in the code below:

```
    HDC Layout = CreateCompatibleDC(0);
    HBITMAP image = CreateCompatibleBitmap(Layout, symbol->bitmap_width, symbol->bitmap_height);
    
    // Draw the image
    
    int bit = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < symbol->bitmap_height; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < symbol->bitmap_width; k++) {
            if (symbol->bitmap[bit] == '1')
                SetPixel(Layout, j, k, rgbBlue);
            else
                SetPixel(Layout, j, k, rgbGreen);
            bit++;
        }
    }

    BOOL success = BitBlt(dc, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, BCLayout, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
```

I expected the image to be displayed in said device context but the image does not display in the end. Does anyone know why that is?

A few things I should clarify:

- the variable "symbol" is a struct variable that holds all the information for the image
- the symbol->bitmap array is a character array that has characters that denote the color of a pixel on the bitmap representation of the image (why it's one-dimensional, I don't know. It was designed that way by a third party)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CreateCompatibleDC()` creates an in-memory `HDC` with a 1x1 monochrome `HBITMAP` assigned to it by default. You need to use [`SelectObject()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-selectobject) to replace that default `HBITMAP` with your own `HBITMAP` before you then use `SetPixel()` to change the `HDC`'s pixels, eg:

```
// create an HDC...
HDC Layout = CreateCompatibleDC(0);

// create a bitmap for the HDC...
HBITMAP image = CreateCompatibleBitmap(Layout, symbol->bitmap_width, symbol->bitmap_height);
    
// replace the default bitmap with the new one...
// remember the old bitmap for later...
HBITMAP oldBmp = (HBITMAP) SelectObject(Layout, image);

// Draw the image as needed...

// restore the previous bitmap...
SelectObject(Layout, oldBmp);

// destroy the new bitmap...
DeleteObject(image);

// destroy the HDC...
DeleteDC(Layout);
```

Comment: So does that mean "oldBmp" would be the first parameter in SetPixel()?

Comment: @WashedJavaProgrammer No, because the 1st parameter of `SetPixel()` expects an `HDC` not an `HBITMAP`.  `oldBmp` is needed because you have to restore the original `HBITMAP` that you replace with `SelectObject()` before you destroy the `HDC`, otherwise that original bitmap will be leaked.

Comment: Oh right. Also, 'HBITMAP oldBmp = SelectObject(Layout, image)' give me a "cannot be initalized as HBITMAP" unless I typecast it as 'HBITMAP'. Is that normal?

Comment: Okay. Just one last thing before I call it quits. For BitBlt(), do the coordinates for the destination rectangle need to be exactly where the rectangle on the destination HDC is or does that not matter? The image is not printing out and I'm not sure if the coordinates I inputted have anything to do with it.

Comment: @WashedJavaProgrammer obviously, the specified rectangle has to fall within both `HDC`s to show anything. You are copying a `1000x1000` pixel square from `Layout` coordinates `0x0` to `dc` coordinates `1000x1000`, is that what you really want? What are the values of `symbol->bitmap_width` and `symbol->bitmap_height`? In any case, `BitBlt()` can't resize a drawn image. If you need to do that, use `StretchBlt()` instead. Also, when calling `CreateCompatibleDC()`, you probably should be passing in the destination `dc`, not `0` (ie, the screen).